# Terraform: What's the point using Both Data Source and Resource on the same type?

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I'm new to Terraform, and I'm working on a project to use Docker/AWS ECR/ECS infrastructure on AWS. I see [in this post](https://medium.com/@hullsean/how-to-setup-an-amazon-ecs-cluster-with-terraform-87952988f239) where the author specify something like

```
data "aws_ecs_task_definition" "test" {
 task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.test.family}"
 depends_on = ["aws_ecs_task_definition.test"]
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "test" {
 family = "test-family"
 # ...
}
```

why is he using both data source AND resource on `aws_ecs_task_definition`? I can't find an explanation or similar example after hours of digging into the official doc as well as googling articles.

I see later on when he's setting up the service, he uses the following code to reference both of them: (again, I'm not sure what's going on here)

`task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.test.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.test.revision}", "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.test.revision}")}"`

I am now confused of what is the difference between using both data & resource on the same type, versus just using resource. Is there any difference in terms of lifecycle?

I'm now trying to create a AWS ECR for my docker image and I want terraform to manage it (create/update/destroy), should I use both data source & resource for the type `aws_ecr_repository` as well?

Comment: the resource creates it and the data source retrieves it.

Comment: In the example above, there is no reason to be using both a `data` and a `resource`. I have to assume the material you viewed was doing so for educational reasons. One reason I have done both is for EBS snapshots, so if someone made a newer snapshot in the console than Terraform made, the latest one is being used where necessary.

Comment: @victorm Thanks for the explanation, that order makes sense, and I guess that's what it does when `terraform apply` executed the 1st time. But how about when I execute `terraform apply` the 2nd time, will it be the same where resource be re-created and data source retrieve it? I'm asking this because I'm thinking of rebuilding the docker image after I make changes and will want to update the infrastructure.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for giving the example, I think that clarifies things. Can you explain more about the EBS snapshot? Is it about something like this: after I create the infrastructure with Terraform, I use AWS CodePipeline to link to my github source code repo. Once I push new code to github repo, the AWS CodePipeline is triggered and task definition is updated. Will that create a EBS snapshot and is that the reason why data source & resource both are needed?

Comment: Terraform is idempotent, when you run it a second time, nothings gets updated unless you made changes to it. The read will still happen. Keep in mind that there are some resources where if you make a change, a new resource gets created. I can't recall if a task_definition is one of them. If a new one gets created you have to update your task service to use the new one.

Comment: I do not know about ECS or CodePipeline because I use the industry standard tools Kubernetes and Jenkins, so I cannot speak to your analogy that specifically, sorry.

Comment: I see, so at least I know now that using data source and resource both won't do anything new. I guess I'll just use resource instead to create the infrastructure and find other tools to update.

Comment: won't there be a race condition if you use data and resource?  I feel like I saw data reads happening before the resource creation like terraform did not know the dependency there.  Or will that actually work just fine as terraform is running as much as it can in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes sense. The guy is using the data source to get the latest task definition revision. This is because he might be using some other tool(jenkins/circleci) to push changes to the task definition or revision.

Hence, if he will run that code again then terraform should pick up the latest version and update the ecs service accordingly.

Check the below code:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "test-ecs-service" {
 name = "test-vz-service"
 cluster = "${aws_ecs_cluster.test-ecs-cluster.id}"
 task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.test.family}:${max("${aws_ecs_task_definition.test.revision}", "${data.aws_ecs_task_definition.test.revision}")}"
 desired_count = 1
 iam_role = "${aws_iam_role.ecs-service-role.name}"

load_balancer {
 target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.test.id}"
 container_name = "nginx"
 container_port = "80"
 }
```

He is updating the service with the latest revision. He is using MAX function which is returning the maximum value. You may check terraform interpolation syntax, [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#max-float1-float2-).

**if the task definition does not exist, will this terraform script create it?**

Yes, It will create it with respect to the task definition which it has in it state file. If you have created task definition manually then it will increment the revision number.

**if task definition exists and the data source block retrieved it, will the resource block re-create another revised task definition, or will it just do nothing?**

If there is a change in any of the configuration of the resource then it will create new task definition and that task definition will be allocated to ecs service resource but if there is no change in the resource then it will do nothing.

**I'm also unclear if this terraform script is intended to run only once (initial infra creation) or upon change?**

This should be run at the time of infra creation or if you wanted to do any other update to task definition resource.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, that solves a lot of my confusion. I guess what I still remain unclear about is that, if the task definition does not exist, will this terraform script create it? And if task definition exists and the data source block retrieved it, will the resource block re-create another revised task definition, or will it just do nothing? I'm also unclear if this terraform script is intended to run only once (initial infra creation) or upon change?

Comment: I have updated the answer, addressing all questions.